# Formidable Pro form - $ Post hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, post, crm, formidable

Hi   I am looking to get a formidable pro web form to send data to my crm system, after the submit button is cliked

I have 90% coded it but for some reason its just not sending the information through

I have added it to my website using code snippets plugin for wordpress, and set the snippet such tht when form x  is submitted it should post various bits of data through to the crm system

The data from the formidable pro form is output in the following format  [21],  or [18]  etc   I have removed this set of brackets from around the data  - as there is already a set of brackets[] in the formatting

attached developers guide and example code from crm system and my own 90% developed code  any ideas why its not connecting ?

My code

```
add_action('frm_after_create_entry', 'yourfunctionname', 30, 2);
function yourfunctionname($entry_id, $form_id){
 if($form_id == 2){ //replace 5 with the id of the form

            //set POST variables
            $url = 'https://secure4.mortgagekeeperonline.co.uk/mywebsitelink/php/NewMortgageQuickDetails.php'; // Your system URL
            $fields = array(
                'StagePK'=>urlencode(25), // Must set Stage
                'AdvisorPK'=>urlencode(1), //Must set Adviser
                'MortgageMode'=>urlencode(0), // 'CommercialMode'=>urlencode(1), [IF CommercialKeeper}

                //Commercial Deatils
                'CompanyName'=>urlencode($_POST['companyName']),
                'ComAddressLine1'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine1']),
                'ComAddressLine2'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine2']),
                'ComAddressLine3'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine3']),
                'ComPostcode'=>urlencode($_POST['companyPostcode']),
                'ComTelephone'=>urlencode($_POST['Office']),
                'ComEmail'=>urlencode($_POST['Email']),
                'LegalStatus'=>urlencode(3),

                //Mortgage Details
                'LenderPK'=>urlencode(1),
                'InterestRateTypePK'=>urlencode(2),
                'Rate'=>urlencode(3.45),
                'DealTerm'=>urlencode(5),
                'Term'=>urlencode(25),
                'ActionPK'=>urlencode(11),
                'ActionText'=>urlencode($_POST['Notes']),

                //Applicant Details
                'Title1'=>urlencode($_POST['10']),
                'Forename1'=>urlencode($_POST['9']),
                'Surname1'=>urlencode($_POST['15']),
                'Email'=>urlencode($_POST['149']),
                'DayPhone'=>urlencode($_POST['28']),
                'MobilePhone'=>urlencode($_POST['29']),
                'Title2'=>urlencode($_POST['12']),
                'Forename2'=>urlencode($_POST['11']),
                'Surname2'=>urlencode($_POST['16']),
                'MidNameApp1'=>urlencode($_POST['13']),
                'MidNameApp2'=>urlencode($_POST['14']),


                //Fact Find Questions   
                'FFVersionPK12'=>urlencode(5), //Must set which FactFind    

                    'FFQuestionPK[1]'=>11884,
                    'FFAnswer[1]'=>urlencode($_POST['23']),  // looking to

                    'FFQuestionPK[2]'=>11885,
                    'FFAnswer[2]'=>urlencode($_POST['24']),  // credit history

                    // Just increment the FFQuestionPK and FFAnswer numbers in the square brackets by 1
                    // Replace the ???? in 'FFQuestionPK[3]'=>????, with the FactFind Question PK number
                    // and replace the ??? in 'FFAnswer[3]'=>urlencode($_POST['????']), with your form post value

                    'FFQuestionPK[3]'=>11463,
                    'FFAnswer[3]'=>urlencode($_POST['43']),  // property value

                    'FFQuestionPK[4]'=>9164,
                    'FFAnswer[4]'=>urlencode($_POST['57']),  // existing loans summary

                    'FFQuestionPK[5]'=>11466,
                    'FFAnswer[5]'=>urlencode($_POST['71']),  // term of mortgage

                    'FFQuestionPK[6]'=>11465,
                    'FFAnswer[6]'=>urlencode($_POST['44']),  // mortgage required

                    'FFQuestionPK[7]'=>8829,
                    'FFAnswer[7]'=>urlencode($_POST['17']),  // app1 DOB

                    'FFQuestionPK[8]'=>9772,
                    'FFAnswer[8]'=>urlencode($_POST['18']),  // app2 dob

                    'FFQuestionPK[9]'=>11886,
                    'FFAnswer[9]'=>urlencode($_POST['19']),  // app1 nationality




                'submit'=>true //Do not remove
                    );

            //url-ify the data for the POST
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string,'&amp;');

            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

            //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //Debug
            //var_dump($result);
            //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

            //Generate eMail (If Required)
            $name1 = $_POST['Forename'];
            $name2 = $_POST['Surname'];
            $phone = $_POST['Office'];
            $email = $_POST['Email'];
            $comments = $_POST['companyName'];

            $message = "*** This is a message sent from the website contact form ***\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "Contact Name: $name1 $name2\r\n";
            $message .= "Contact Number: $phone\r\n";
            $message .= "Email: $email\r\n";
            $message .= "Business: $comments\r\n\r\n------------ END -------------";

            if(mail('info@DOMAIN.co.uk', 'Website Contact Form', $message, "From: YOU@DOMAIN.co.uk\r\n")) {
                $emailStatus = 'Form Sent.';
            }else{
                $emailStatus = 'Form Not Sent. Please contact NAME on TELEPHONE.';
            }

            //close connection
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }


==end code==

the developers example code was 

<?php

            //set POST variables
            $url = 'https://secure.mortgagekeeperonline.co.uk/SITENAME/php/NewMortgageQuickDetails.php'; // Your system URL
            $fields = array(
                'StagePK'=>urlencode(1), // Must set Stage
                'AdvisorPK'=>urlencode(4), //Must set Adviser
                'MortgageMode'=>urlencode(1), // 'CommercialMode'=>urlencode(1), [IF CommercialKeeper}

                //Commercial Deatils
                'CompanyName'=>urlencode($_POST['companyName']),
                'ComAddressLine1'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine1']),
                'ComAddressLine2'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine2']),
                'ComAddressLine3'=>urlencode($_POST['companyAddressLine3']),
                'ComPostcode'=>urlencode($_POST['companyPostcode']),
                'ComTelephone'=>urlencode($_POST['Office']),
                'ComEmail'=>urlencode($_POST['Email']),
                'LegalStatus'=>urlencode(3),

                //Mortgage Details
                'LenderPK'=>urlencode(1),
                'InterestRateTypePK'=>urlencode(2),
                'Rate'=>urlencode(3.45),
                'DealTerm'=>urlencode(5),
                'Term'=>urlencode(25),
                'ActionPK'=>urlencode(11),
                'ActionText'=>urlencode($_POST['Notes']),

                //Applicant Details
                'Title1'=>urlencode($_POST['Title']),
                'Forename1'=>urlencode($_POST['Forename']),
                'Surname1'=>urlencode($_POST['Surname']),
                'Email'=>urlencode($_POST['Email']),
                'DayPhone'=>urlencode($_POST['Office']),
                'MobilePhone'=>urlencode($_POST['Mobile']),

                //Fact Find Questions   
                'FFVersionPK'=>urlencode(5), //Must set which FactFind  

                    'FFQuestionPK[1]'=>11604,
                    'FFAnswer[1]'=>urlencode($_POST['datemoved1']),

                    'FFQuestionPK[2]'=>11636,
                    'FFAnswer[2]'=>urlencode($_POST['basic1']),

                    // Just increment the FFQuestionPK and FFAnswer numbers in the square brackets by 1
                    // Replace the ???? in 'FFQuestionPK[3]'=>????, with the FactFind Question PK number
                    // and replace the ??? in 'FFAnswer[3]'=>urlencode($_POST['????']), with your form post value

                    'FFQuestionPK[3]'=>????,
                    'FFAnswer[3]'=>urlencode($_POST['????']),

                'submit'=>true //Do not remove
                    );

            //url-ify the data for the POST
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string,'&amp;');

            //open connection
            $ch = curl_init();

            //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

            //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            //Debug
            //var_dump($result);
            //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));

            //Generate eMail (If Required)
            $name1 = $_POST['Forename'];
            $name2 = $_POST['Surname'];
            $phone = $_POST['Office'];
            $email = $_POST['Email'];
            $comments = $_POST['companyName'];

            $message = "*** This is a message sent from the website contact form ***\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "Contact Name: $name1 $name2\r\n";
            $message .= "Contact Number: $phone\r\n";
            $message .= "Email: $email\r\n";
            $message .= "Business: $comments\r\n\r\n------------ END -------------";

            if(mail('info@DOMAIN.co.uk', 'Website Contact Form', $message, "From: YOU@DOMAIN.co.uk\r\n")) {
                $emailStatus = 'Form Sent.';
            }else{
                $emailStatus = 'Form Not Sent. Please contact NAME on TELEPHONE.';
            }

            //close connection
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">
<TITLE>Contact Form</TITLE>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div>

<?php echo "Email Status: $emailStatus"; ?>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <table width="450px" border="0">
            <th colspan="2">Company Details</th>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="companyName">Company Name</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="companyName" value="<?php echo $_POST['companyName']; ?>" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="companyAddressLine1">Company Address</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="companyAddressLine1" value="<?php echo $_POST['companyAddressLine1']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="companyAddressLine2"></label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="companyAddressLine2" value="<?php echo $_POST['companyAddressLine2']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="companyAddressLine3">Town</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="companyAddressLine3" value="<?php echo $_POST['companyAddressLine3']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="companyPostcode">Postcode</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="companyPostcode" value="<?php echo $_POST['companyPostcode']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <th colspan="2">Your Details</th>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="Title">Title</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <select name="Title">
                                      <option value="1">Mr</option>
                                      <option value="2">Mrs</option>
                                      <option value="3">Miss</option>
                                      <option value="4">Ms</option>
                                  </select> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="Forename">First Name</label> </td>  
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="Forename" value="<?php echo $_POST['Forename']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="surname">Surname</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="Surname" value="<?php echo $_POST['Surname']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="Email">Email</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $_POST['Email']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="Office">Office Telephone</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="Office" value="<?php echo $_POST['Office']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <label for="Mobile">Mobile</label> </td>
                <td valign="top"> <input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo $_POST['Mobile']; ?>"/> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td valign="top"> <input name="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit"> <a href=""></a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</DIV>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$_POST['item_meta'][30]` just as it is say in your page: https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/frm_after_create_entry/